# cuda-gdb: Meaning/occurence of "CUDA_EXCEPTION_9: Warp Hardware Stack Overflow"

Tags: exception, gdb, cuda, nvidia

The manual for cuda-gdb and for cuda-memcheck mention the above CUDA_EXCEPTION_9: "Warp Hardware Stack Overflow" but I have not been able to find further details; the only comment given in both manuals is

> "This occurs when any thread in a warp triggers a hardware stack overflow. This should be a rare occurrence."

In my case it sometimes (!?) occurs when I try to dynamically allocate memory on the device via malloc() (processing the same set of data!). Trying to malloc() 0 bytes (bug has been fixed) repeatedly caused the same exception.

What precisely causes this exception under which circumstances; what does it indicate, how can one fix/circumvent it?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

A stack overflow on a Fermi GPU is no different to a stack overflow on any other device. Each thread gets a static stack and heap allocation from global memory at launch. If you exhaust the stack via excessive recursion, allocate more that the available heap memory, or try operating out of bounds on any variable stored in heap memory, a protection fault is generated, and you will get a stack overflow error reported. From your question, I would guess that you are exhausting the available per-thread heap space via device side malloc calls.

The CUDA runtime API includes functions for managing stack and heap memory [cudaDeviceSetLimit](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/html/group__CUDART__DEVICE_gb8a22e29cc297634b0702db0b69f59e7.html#gb8a22e29cc297634b0702db0b69f59e7) and [cudaDeviceGetLimit](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/html/group__CUDART__DEVICE_g50e098f554dbfca0ef054e7b7d39d06e.html#g50e098f554dbfca0ef054e7b7d39d06e). With these you can check how much stack, heap and `printf` FIFO each thread is being given by the runtime, and try increasing the heap and stack size to see if your problem goes away.